# php unseting $_SESSION variable on page referesh or redirected

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have moved our code to new server PHP version is 7.1 previously used were 5.6.

I am facing problems on $_SESSION variable. if page is redirected to other pages $_SESSION is have no values, even I reload this page again after commented session set as well $_SESSION values are gone.

```
ob_start(); session_start();
$_SESSION['abc'] = "manik";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
session_regenerate_id(true);
header('Location:test2.php');
exit();
```

[session_save_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRj8z.png)

Please advise.

Comment: So you code was working in same browser using old PHP version ?

Comment: yes when moved to new server its not working , i think its something session_save_path issue, local is saved there but master value not

Comment: So remove session_save_path from your script and test it with default tmp folder to see if it works :)

Comment: no its not working with temp folder as well

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: issue has been resolved with SSL implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check you session.save_path i THINK SO ITS NOT writable That's why ur facing this issue
    `if (!is_writable(session_save_path()))
    {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!';
    }`

Answer (score 0):

save your variables in an array first. Then, set session data using set_userdata method. 
Example:

```
$session_data = array('abc' => 'manik');
```

Then,

```
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

Hope, this works